Should we organize community actions on Crypto.SE?
I recentely discovered, that back in the days, when Crypto.SE was still in Beta and wasn't all that old, we had this Meta-Question about Crypto-Challenges on Crypto.SE..
Now I know that we don't want to do enocurage any of these "analyze my data please" question - which is the standard idea for this sort of crypto thing.
But generally I think community challenges / competitions / whatever are accepted by SE (see the linked question) and I think this may actually be fun (not sure if I'm allowed to use this word here).
So the question would be:

Do we want community challenges / competitions?
Do we want Crypto.SE community based efforts? (for example a submission to the Snake-Oil Competition or the Journal Of Craptology)
What could we do if not those "decipher my data" challenges? (I know that CodeRev asks for programs sometimes, but we obviously can't do that...)

And finally the most important question:
Are we allowed to sometimes have fun (again this mean word) on Crypto.SE?

wow, we really lack tags for meta. I just had to create those four new tags for this question :O.
